# I keep getting a segfault when trying to pass a struct node* and then print using printf

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, nodes

Full code here: https://gist.github.com/IamSlightly/5debd2373231a62c0a44665902e9ca7f

Not sure exactly why this is happening but it happens in line 43 when the printf tries to access the returned value.

```
struct node* kv = Lookup (13);
if (kv)
    printf ("%s\n", kv->val_ptr);

struct node* Lookup(int x){
  struct node *holder;
  holder = head;
  while ((holder->key!=x) && (holder->next!=NULL)){
    holder = holder->next;
  }
  if (holder->key==x) {
    printf("\nlets try this shit again\n");
    return holder;
  } else {
    printf("\n*** %d is not in the linked_list ***\n", x);
    return NULL;
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `kv->val_ptr`?

Comment: Step through the code with your debugger, and see what the values of the variables are when it fails.

Comment: Try actually including some *function prototypes* in your header file. Right now `main.c` is pulling in linked_list.h, which contains the structure definition, but does *not* contain the prototypes for `Insert`, `Lookup`, etc. As a result, all those functions take on implicit declarations of functions returning `int` with variadic parameter lists. And I'm willing to bet on your build/run rig `int` and `struct node *` are *not* the same size. Thus `int Lookup()` is returning something, but it sure isn't a valid pointer. You should be receiving a plethora of warnings about this, btw.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't do that

Comment: @plzhelpme it could be worse. you could have run/tested this on a 32bit platform that completely masked that problem, thought life was grand, then had some prof test it on a 64bit platform and witnessed your grade tank.

Comment: Still not working though

Comment: Yeah, but that's a huge issue to take care of it was certainly wrong as it was. Pax has other issues in his answer that warrant review. Address those as well, and above all, *turn up your warning levels to pedantic levels*, and fix what is flagged.

Comment: Just did and there are a few for pointer type differences but I still don't understand why the issue only arises when I pass the object.

Answer (score 2):

If you're crashing on:

```
printf ("%s\n", kv->val_ptr);
```

then it's a safe bet that either `kv` or `kv->val_ptr` are not pointing to something that's "kosher".

Since your `Lookup` code seems to preclude returning an invalid pointer (assuming of course you haven't screwed up the *creation* of the linked list), it's likely that the `val_ptr` field hasn't been set correctly, or it's pointing at something that isn't a string.

Your best bet is to use a debugger (or `printf` lines if you don't have a decent one) and examine values *before* attempting to use them. That will greatly assist you in figuring out the root cause.

If you were to go the `printf` route (I'd prefer a debugger but it's not always an option), I would be looking at code like the following, place before your own `if (kv)` line:

```
if (kv) {
    printf ("Starting DEBUG\n");
    fflush (stdout); fsync (fileno (stdout));

    printf ("kv as pointer is %p\n", kv);
    fflush (stdout); fsync (fileno (stdout));

    printf ("kv->val_ptr as pointer is %p\n", kv->val_ptr);
    fflush (stdout); fsync (fileno (stdout));

    printf ("kv->val_ptr as char[10] is %10.10s\n");
    fflush (stdout); fsync (fileno (stdout));

    printf ("Ending DEBUG\n");
    fflush (stdout); fsync (fileno (stdout));
}
```

This shows how to write debugging statements in such a way that they'll be flushed before the core dump stops output.

Basically, what you need to do is to narrow down the issue gradually until you can isolate it to a specific line, then work out what's wrong with that line :-)

---

As an aside, if an empty list will consist of `head` being set to `NULL`, that `Lookup` code is going to crash on you. That's probably not the case here since you've stated it's the actual `printf` line which is crashing.

A better one would be something like:

```
struct node* Lookup (int x) {
    struct node *holder = head;
    while (holder != NULL)
        if (holder->key == x)
            return holder;
    return NULL;
}
```

---

In addition, based on the code at the link you gave, you may want to add function prototypes to your header file. You have the structure and variables such as `head` but it's a good idea for any code using your implementation to have properly-defined definitions for the functions within it. As an example, it should contain something like:

```
int Insert(int, char*, int);
```

for the `Insert` function, ditto for the other functions you wish to call.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, gonna give it a shot.

Comment: Starting DEBUG
holder as pointer is 0x7f9e3a80c000
holder->val_ptr as pointer is 0x7f9e3a80c200
Segmentation fault: 11 Just gotta figureout what to do with this

Comment: @plzhelpme, then your issue is that you're treating `val_ptr` as a string and it's not. That may be as simple as ensuring it's nul-terminated or it may be as complex as a memory corruption caused elsewhere. However, the debugging approach is what will eventually lead you to the answer.